# Laravel template does not execute code inside curly brackets

Tags: php, laravel, echo, laravel-blade, curly-braces

I am trying to echo a variable inside an include file.

```
@include('path.to.some.file')
<?php $var = "Hello World";?>
{!!$var!!}
```

But when i open the browser i see original code as

```
{!!$var!!}
```

instead of the string value assigned to the variable.

However, there is smooth execution of everything on any files without being called through @include.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please specify your include file code here.

Comment: Does the included file have a .blade.php ending or just a .php one?

Answer (score 4):

OK, after a couple of checkings i just came to see the funny incident that my include file was missing a .blade word in its name, in other words file.blade.php should work fine instead of file.php

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file ends with `.blade.php`, not only `.php`.

Answer (score 1):

check your file name, is it file_name.blade.php

Answer (score -1):

try to use {{ $var }}. I believe your current output is a comment.

Comment: It is not. And if it were, it wouldn't print. {!! ... !!] is for unescaped printing in Laravel 5.